# Line up images using setCompoundDrawable()

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

I just learned about `TextView.setCompoundDrawables()` and I'm using it in a ListView to place an image to the left of my text. The problem is that the thumbnail images are different sizes, so the text wanders all over the place. Is there a simple way to get the text to line up nicely on the left-hand side?

**Code:**

```
        TextView machineText = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        machineText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(thumbnail,
                null, null, null);
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: show some code or screenshot of your issue.

Comment: @GrIsHu There you go.

Comment: Are you inflating images dynamically ?

Comment: I suggest you to set the images in `ImageView` besides setting it into the `TextView` As you can not manage the height and width of the image which you have set in TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play around with  setCompoundDrawablePadding (int pad) to dynamically changed the padding between the drawable and the text. What you should really do though is write your own ListAdapter and layout each image and text in a custom listitem layout. Would be much easier. My experience is that bitmap compoundDrawables can look a lot different on different devices.

Answer (score 1):

Imageview / ImageButton are the only views I am familiar with that give you scaling control.

If you put the pics in imageviews and the textviews to the right, you will get the same effect with more control.  You can then scale the images.  ScaleType = fitxy will ensure the image is drawn to both xy borders.  The downside is the images may appear stretched, if they don't fit naturally.   But there's other scaletypes you can play with too.

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_iv"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/overflow"

     />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/my_iv"
        />
```

I haven't used the TextView + drawable option, but you can also try ensuring that the images are the same size intrinsically.  I'm not sure how android chooses the drawable size when part of the textview, so i'm not sure if that will work.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
TextView machineText = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
thumbnail.setBounds(60, 60, 60, 60);
machineText.setCompoundDrawables(bd, null, null, null);
```

instead of 60 set the bounds as you need it.

Comment: Or I could just do `thumbnail.setBounds(...)`